# why backslash as escape character instead of a less-used character?

Tags: c++, regex, escaping

In C/C++ (and other languages) the escape character is a backslash. But the backslash is popular (in paths/regexes). Why is not a less popular character, such as a tilde (~) or expononent (^) used?

Comment: +1 for interesting question... voting to close for not constructive, because there won't be a good solid answer to this question. :-( Sorry.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Why? I’m pretty sure there was some kind of reasoning behind this when it was defined for the first time…

Comment: @poke: It must be the "instead of a less-used character"/"Why is not a less popular character" part.

Comment: You can always use a raw string literal if you don't want to escape.

Comment: it is used often, so authors chose symbol which is in convenient place. you don't need to press shift and move your hand far.

Comment: Remember that it's only used in paths on Windows. Everyone else uses forward slashes (which Windows will usually accept anyway).

Comment: I would imagine that backslash was chosen simply because it is established as the escape character in many other contexts.

Comment: The point about regexes is valid, though, since Unix popularized both the now-common regex syntax and the use of backslash as an escape character.

Comment: @poke: I suppose that's possible. I'll remove my close vote. But you have to admit, this question invites a lot of speculation, and if that's what this turns out to be, then I'd rather this be closed. (EDIT: I can't remove my close vote, oops. If this closes, I'll vote to reopen.)

Comment: @larsmans So then it’s only consistent: use the same escape character throughout. Which renders this whole question moot: whichever character would have been chosen would cause conflicts, if it were adopted throughout. Asking this simply makes no sense.

Comment: this should be on [retrocomputing.se]. See also [Why does Windows use backslashes for paths and Unix forward slashes?](https://superuser.com/q/176388/241386), [Slash versus backslash as directory separator - what/who caused this rift?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4695/1981)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question should be the other way around: why was the backslash, which until the early 1980s was mainly used for escape characters, chosen as a path separator in MS-DOS? See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx) for the answer.

Comment: interesting question... some googling provided this article (http://www.trailing-edge.com/~bobbemer/ESCAPE.HTM) which mentions that : "An example of the latter is the "\" as used by C and such. Ever see "\t" in text cause a Horizontal Tab movement? I haven't. The reason is that it may be descriptive, as in general text, or announcing, as it is in source programs for the compiler for the programming language C and its offshoots. C could just as well have used "|announce|t", but the backslash fascinated with its brevity, preceding Microsoft's using it for their file hierarchy indicator"